# Android Splash Screen shifts

Tags: android, react-native

I have an Android Splash Screen which renders a drawable. When it is opened via a cold start, I find that my asset simply shifts in an upward direction.

You can find the appropriate code below, all unnecessary code has been omitted.

Here's the slight shift:

[image]

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

res/drawable/background_splash.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
    <item android:drawable="@color/splash_background_color"/>
    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/x150"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

res/layout/launch_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/splash_background_color">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/background_splash"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Probably, it's because you have a transparent status bar. Try to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your root `FrameLayout`

Comment: @TarasParshenko thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately it still exists with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true">`.

Comment: hey, i am stuck in a similar error, btw can u tell me the import line for `AppCompatActivity` in `SplashActivity.java`

Comment: Me too. Android pixel 3a is good. but Galaxy S10 shift!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

You should remove `ImageView` because you've already set splash via `android:windowBackground`.
Also remove `android:background="@color/splash_background_color"` from `FrameLayout` to make it transparent

Btw, you could delete `res/layout/launch_screen.xml` if you are not going to draw some layouts over your splash.

For `Activity` don't call `setContentView()`

For `Fragment` don't override `onCreateView()`

It's ok, Android doesn't require to set layout for them.

Comment: Removing this value means it doesn't render the first time. It shows a white screen and then the logo. As appose to constantly showing the logo.

Comment: In this case `ImageView` could be removed. The issue is `android:windowBackground` and `<ImageView android:layout_gravity="center">` render in different way. Looks like `windowBackground` has more space, so bitmap shifts upward

Comment: If I am following correctly, removing `ImageView` now renders nothing.

Comment: Yeah, you should also remove `android:background="@color/splash_background_color"` from `FrameLayout` to make it transparent

Comment: Thank you very much, if you could update your answer with the things in the comments I'll upvote and accept. Just a question, is `launch_screen.xml` required if it's only rendering a transparent FrameLayout?

Comment: borderless devices problem??
I changed style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar to style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen in "android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml".
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/844

Answer (score 4):

In `styles.xml`, replace:

```xml
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
```

with

```xml
<item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
```

Note the `windowBackground` `->` `background`

That solves the issue for me.

Comment: your are the best